Why does time fall behind on domain controller and then stops falling behind?
My Windows 11 Pro machine (Lenovo; System Model 20TKCTO1WW) time falls behind the domain controller time. I connect to vpn, run net time \\[dc computer name] /set /y and it is back in sync.
The weird part to me is it falls behind again but then stops. I would expect the drift to continue indefinitely.
It stops falling behind around ~1min 45secs.
That implies there is something else going on here. Anyone else seen this? All Lenovo updates applied, Windows updates up to date.
It happened on Windows 10 too.

Evidently, it syncs automatically to another server when you're not on VPN. Look at time server settings to find out to what it syncs.
